# Django: How to display some objects to specific users only

Tags: html, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I am new to django and working on a project where admin have to assign a team to manager and when ever admin assign a team to manager then it will be shown on that manager's dashboard only.I have no idea how can i do this. Please if someone can help please help me.

here is my .html file for admin from where admin can assign team to manager.

```
<th>S No.</th>
<th>COMPANY NAME</th>
<th>TEAM MEMBER</th>
  <th>Assign TEAM</th>
</tr>
</thead>
 <tbody>
 {%for team in object%}
   <tr>
     <form id="form_id" method="POST" action = "{% url 'accept' %}">
       {% csrf_token %}
      <th scope="row"> {{ forloop.counter }}</th>
       <td>{{team.company_name}}</td>
        <td>{{team.team_member}}</td>
          <td>
             <select name="manager_{{manager.id}}">
              {% for manager in managers %}
                <option value ="{{manager.id}}">{{manager.name}}</option>
              {% endfor %}                                   
               </select>
           </td>
             <td>
                 <input class="btn btn-raised btn-primary btn-round waves-effect" type="submit" value="Assign">
                            </td>
            </tr>
             {% endfor %}
```

here is my model for the team and manager:

```
class Create_Team(models.Model):
 first_name = models.CharField(max_length= 50)
 last_name = models.CharField(max_length= 50)
 company_name = models.CharField(max_length= 100)
 address = models.CharField(max_length= 1000)
 state = models.CharField(max_length= 100)
 city = models.CharField(max_length= 100)
 status = models.CharField(max_length= 30)
 managers = models.ForeignKey('manager', on_delete = models.SET_NULL, null=True)

class manager(models.Model):
 name = models.CharField(max_length= 500)
 designation = models.CharField(max_length= 500)
```

here is my views.py file for manager and from where the admin is accepting the request:

```
def accept(request):
obj= Create_Team.objects.filter(status='Accept') 
managers = manager.objects.all()
if request.method == 'POST':
   createteam = Create_Team()
   createteam_id = int(request.POST.get('team', 1))
   manager_id = int(request.POST.get('manager', 1))
   createteam = Create_Team.objects.get(pk=createteam_id)
   createteam.manager = manager.objects.get(pk=manager_id)
   createteam.save()

  return render(request, "admin/accept.html", {"object": obj,  "managers": managers})

def superior(request):
return render(request, 'manager/index-3.html')
```

here is my views where i am checking whether the user is admin or user or manager

```
def login(request):
if request.method =='POST':
    # print(request.POST)
    username = request.POST['username']
    password = request.POST['password']

    user = auth.authenticate(username=username, password=password)

    if user is not None:
        auth.login(request, user)
        print (user.has_perm('app.edit_task'))
        # return redirect('index')

        if user.is_superuser:
            return redirect('master')

        # elif user.has_perm('app.edit_task'):
        #     return redirect('manager')
        elif user.is_staff:
            return redirect('manager')
        else:
            return redirect('index')

    else:
        messages.error(request, 'Invalid Credentials')
        return redirect('login')    
else: 
    return render(request, 'vadash/sign-in.html')
```

I want that whenever the admin will click on the assign button then that team will be displayed to that manager.Please help me. But this code isn't updating the database.

Answer (score 0):

After Manager Logins, Make sure that you retrieve the data of the manager that is logged in. and pass that data to the view

Comment: after the manager will login i need that the team that is assigned to that manager will be displayed to him only

Answer (score 0):

Make custom user Model to check if logged in user is manager,admin or member.

You can make custom user by different methods.Please check the link:

https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/22/how-to-extend-django-user-model.html

You might give boolean fields like is_manager , is_member etc

After defining custom user model you can check if logged in user is manager ,admin etc using

```
request.user.is_manager == True
```

Comment: i want that when ever admin assign a team to manager then that team will be displayed only on that manager's dashboard and the name of the manage should be displayed in the backend

Comment: dont name your model like create team . Its a table name keep it as Team .. If manager can be assigned multiple teams,then team should be many to many field in Manager Model.If single ,then make as foreign key . you can set the value of team whenever admin assigns it by updating the model . To display team inside manager dashboard you can siply call this using manager.team

Comment: i have add a foreign key now. But how can i "you can set the value of team whenever admin assigns it by updating the model . To display team inside manager dashboard you can siply call this using manager.team "  do this.

Comment: After you get the specific entry in manager model using Manager.objects.get() , you can set the foreign key like manager.team = the team to be assigned . Make sure you allow null values in team field . And call manager.save() . Or you can use .update() method as well

Comment: if manager is type of user you should create custom user model or add foreign key to user inside manager model

Comment: yes manager is a type of user who have some special permission and he has his is_staff status is true

Comment: your code might need complete redesign.i suggest you read about formsets , forms,how to design urls in django

Comment: the link that you provide me in your answer can help me or not